# android : trouble with Switch.OnCheckChangedListener in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

so I have a `recyclerview` which has a Switch button on each item. the status of switch buttons depends on the data from `sharedpreferance`, which I check in `onBindViewHolder` method.

as you know each item recycles while scrolling, and the `onBindviewHolder` is being called each time, and with this, I cannot control the `Switch.OncheckChangedListener` because the switch status keeps changing every second(while scrolling).

using  `OnClickListener` seemed a good idea at first, but it fails when user swipes to toggle Switch.

Comment: the status of Switch Buttons should be in your data set(you pass to your adapter), i dont know why you store them in SharedPreferance?

Answer (score 0):

Some work around, it may work or not, but give a shot set a flag true in `getView()` method in the adapter, during `Switch.OncheckChangedListener` method call, if the flag is false do your logic, otherwise set the flag false.
e.g

```
boolean isRecycleViewCall = false;
getView() {
isRecycleViewCall = true;
}
Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(!isRecycleViewCall) {
                   //your code
                } else {
                   isRecycleViewCall = false;
                }     
            }
        });
```